# After Convert Visual Studio 2013 project to Visual Studio 2010 my program can't read Database

Tags: visual-studio-2010

after i convert my Visual Basic project 2013 to 2010, i found a problem is, my program can't read database at all, but i open the previous 2013 Visual Basic project, it can read database or i open my friend 2010 Visual Basic project also can read database. I already tried many time to edit the .sln file and read the code properly to make sure i din wrote the wrong database address. Have anybody have this experience before about this problem? Thank you for everyone who seen my post and comment. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go "My Project" "Compile" tab, at "Target CPU" there change to x86, because Microsoft does not have driver on 64bit windows.